# How can I get the current color of a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, colors

How can I get the current color of a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) which in turn is a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

You can use [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)'s method [getBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29) which will give you a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). Now if you set the background of the [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) to be a color, you can cast that [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) to a [ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) and then use the method [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#getColor%28%29)

Comment: Thanks very much, This is my code:                                                 LinearLayout mScreen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myScreen);               ColorDrawable cD = (ColorDrawable)mScreen.getBackground();                   but cD not method getColor(); Sorry but I very noob

Comment: hm it seems that method is available in API level 11 and above only. Take a look at this post : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4910bae94510ef77?pli=1